# Merging OSM PBF files?

Tags: openstreetmap, osm2pgsql, phyghtmap

I have a few (~50) PBF files came from SRTM conversion using phyghtmap.

How to merge all of them before importing with osm2pgsql?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) for merging:

`osmium merge file1.osm file2.osm -o merged.osm`.

Alternatively try [osmosis](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis):

`osmosis --rx file1.osm --rx file2.osm --merge --wx merged.osm`

Note that osmosis has a weird syntax and you need to specify the `--merge` commands `n-1` times for merging `n` files.

Comment: Ok. But how to merge several files at once? I have a lot of them.

Comment: Just specify as many files as you want: `omium merge file*.osm -o merged.osm`.

Comment: BTW: Can I do the same with PBF files?

Comment: Can't find `merge` option. : http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/manual.html#command-line-completion

Comment: @MagnoC Yes, osmium also supports PBF files. The merge option is documented here: http://docs.osmcode.org/osmium/latest/osmium-merge.html

Comment: For PBF files use `osmosis --rb file1.osm --rb file2.osm --merge --wb merged.osm`. `rx` is for XML files.

Answer (score 8):

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install osmium-tool
osmium cat new-york.osm.pbf new-jersey.osm.pbf connecticut.osm.pbf -o ny-nj-ct.osm.pbf
```

Comment: Easy to follow these for osmium with the following version
```>> osmium --version
```
```
osmium version 1.16.0
libosmium version 2.20.0
Supported PBF compression types: none zlib lz4```

Comment: Note that `osmium cat` is often not what you want, take a look at `osmium merge` instead!

Answer (score 1):

osmconvert did trick for me on windows for two files.

```
osmconvert a.pbf --out-o5m | osmconvert - b.pbf -o=all.pbf
```

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert